# Can I optimise this further so that it runs faster?

Tags: performance, go, complexity-theory

As you can see in the following pprof output, I have these nested for loops which take most of the time of my program. Source is in golang but code is explained below:

```
  8.55mins    1.18hrs     20:   for k := range mapSource {
  4.41mins    1.20hrs     21:           if positions, found := mapTarget[k]; found {
         .          .     22:                   // save all matches
  1.05mins   1.05mins     23:                   for _, targetPos := range positions {
  2.25mins   2.33mins     24:                           for _, sourcePos := range mapSource[k] {
     1.28s     15.78s     25:                                   matches = append(matches, match{int32(targetPos), int32(sourcePos)})
         .          .     26:                           }
         .          .     27:                   }
         .          .     28:           }
         .          .     29:   }
```

At the moment the structures I'm using are 2 `map[int32][]int32`, targetMap and sourceMap.

These maps contain, for a given key, an array of ints. Now I want to find the keys that match in both maps, and save the combinations of the elements in the arrays.

So for example:

```
sourceMap[1] = [3,4]
sourceMap[5] = [9,10]

targetMap[1] = [1,2,3]
targetMap[2] = [2,3]
targetMap[3] = [1,2]
```

The only key in common is `1` and the result will be `[(3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3)]`

Is there any possible way (a more appropriate data structure or whatever) that could improve the speed of my program?

In my case, maps can contain somewhere between 1000 and 150000 keys, while the arrays inside are usually pretty small.

EDIT: Concurrency is not an option as this is already being run several times in several threads at the same time.

Comment: For one thing, you could take the value in the outermost loop (`for k :=` -> `for k,v :=`) which would eliminate the extra lookup in the innermost loop (`:= range mapSource[k]` -> `:= range v`). There's also no need to cast `targetPos` and `sourcePos` to `int32` since they're already `int32` according to your question. Overall though maps are likely the most efficient structure. If you have some idea the size of the final data set, or a minimum size, you could preallocate `matches` with that capacity.

Comment: are the arrays always sorted (like in your example)?

Comment: Not sure how much it will help, but `for _, x := range slice {` format will redeclare x and assign the value to it on each iteration. Try using indexed values instead and see if it helps at all. `for i := range slice { ... slice[i]`

Comment: @dave yes, they are

Comment: Maybe keep yet another map of source key ==> target keys.  That will remove the sequential iteration of the target maps for each source key.

Comment: Could you provide a sample data? There is no obvious improvement IMO. If you provide data maybe we could use another data structure or data model to improve query time. Also please specify how `sourceMap`/`targetMap` (or a specific value in them) would change. Maybe we could cache something.

Comment: The top level operation is an intersection between two sets of integers - the keys in mapTarget and mapSource. If the intersection is significantly smaller than the input sets there are algorithms that have better behavior than the linear scan you do now. If the domain of the keys is limited there are linear algorithms that are much better performing than your current code (bitmaps). I know too little about your data to be able to say more. For now in your current code add: `if len(mapSource) > len(mapTarget) { mapSource, mapTarget = mapTarget, mapSource }`

Comment: The answer to the question title as phrased is _always_ "PROBABLY!" =P

Answer (score 5):

> Can I optimise this further so that it runs faster?
>
> Is there any possible way (a more appropriate data structure or
>   whatever) that could improve the speed of my program?

Probably.

---

> The [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) is asking about your
>   attempted solution rather than your actual problem. This leads to
>   enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part of people
>   asking for help, and on the part of those providing help.

---

We don't have even the most basic information about your problem, a description of the form, content, and frequency of your original input data, and your desired output. What original data should drive a benchmark?

I created some fictional original data, which produced some fictional output and results:

```
BenchmarkPeterSO-4   30    44089894 ns/op    5776666 B/op      31 allocs/op
BenchmarkIvan-4      10   152300554 ns/op   26023924 B/op    6022 allocs/op
```

It is possible that your algorithms are slow.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it like this so that I can do some of the work concurrently:

https://play.golang.org/p/JHAmPRh7jr

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var final [][]int32
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var receiver chan []int32
func main() {
    final = [][]int32{}
    mapTarget := make(map[int32][]int32)
    mapSource := make(map[int32][]int32)
    mapSource[1] = []int32{3, 4}
    mapSource[5] = []int32{9, 10}

    mapTarget[1] = []int32{1, 2, 3}
    mapTarget[2] = []int32{2, 3}
    mapTarget[3] = []int32{1, 2}
    wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    receiver = make(chan []int32)
    go func() {
        for elem := range receiver {
            final = append(final, elem)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()
    for k := range mapSource {
        if _, ok := mapTarget[k]; ok {
            wg.Add(1)
            go permutate(mapSource[k], mapTarget[k])
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(final)

}

func permutate(a, b []int32) {
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(b); j++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            receiver <- []int32{a[i], b[j]}
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

You may even want to see if you get any benefit from this:

```
for k := range mapSource {
      wg.Add(1)
      go func(k int32) {
          if _, ok := mapTarget[k]; ok {
              wg.Add(1)
              go permutate(mapSource[k], mapTarget[k])
          }
          wg.Done()
      }(k)
 }
```

Comment: This code has a race condition because there are multiple goroutines writing to `final` concurrently. If you wrap it in a mutex my hunch this version will perform much slower than the original because you're going to have *constant* contention for that lock.

Comment: The point is (1) the code as written will not work  (2) You can solve that with 
channels, but then you're back to square one where you a single goroutine is doing all the appends to the array, except you've added a whole bunch of goroutines to the mix so I guarantee it will perform worse than the OP's code.

Comment: @Ivan, I'd be curious to see a benchmark on your original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The best optimization probably involves changing the source and target data structures to begin with so you're don't have to iterate as much, but it's hard to be sure without knowing more about what the underlying problem you're solving is, and how the maps are generated.

However, there is an optimization that should get you a roughly 2x boost (just an educated guess), depending on the exact numbers.

```
var sources, targets []int32

for k, srcPositions := range mapSource {
    if tgtPositions, found := mapTarget[k]; found {
        sources = append(sources, srcPositions...)
        targets = append(targets, tgtPositions...)
    }
}

matches = make([]match, len(sources) * len(targets))
i := 0
for _, s := range(sources) {
    for _, t := range(targets) {
        matches[i] = match{s, t}
        i++
    }
}
```

The general idea is to minimize the amount of copying that has to be done, and improve the locality of memory references. I think this is about the best you can do with this data structure. My hunch is this isn't the best datastructure to begin with for the underlying problem, and there are much bigger gains to be had.

Answer (score -1):

At first I was thinking:

1. Calculate keys in common in one batch, and calculate the final slice size.
2. Make slice with capacity that step 1 calculated.
3. Append one by one.

Then next structure, but it would not generate final result as array, but all the append work would be just link the node.

```
type node struct {
    val    int
    parent *node
    next   *node
    child  *node
}

type tree struct {
    root  *node
    level int
}

var sourceMap map[int]*tree
```